# Auto positional number about double at printf like cout

Tags: c, printf, double

In C++, using `cout` makes easy to print double type.
when,

```
double pi = 3.14;
cout << pi;
```

It prints

```
3.14
```

but, in C, using `printf`,

```
double pi = 3.14;
printf("%f", pi);
```

It prints

```
3.14000000.. // maybe format like this.
```

I can print more pretty by using `%.2f` but,

when `pi = 3.141` ?

when `pi = 3.1415` ?

code should change to `%.3f`, `%.4f`?

but `cout` in C++ automatically change this format so it prints

```
3.14
3.141
3.1415
```

Just using `cout << pi;`

So, what I want to know is can I do this in C? not using `cout`.

I must use `FILE` pointer. so I can't use `cout`.

But want to print double type pretty. not like 3.1400000... so ugly.

And not use `%.2f`, `.3f` ...

It should be flexible to value of double.

How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe you could use `%g` if you can live with exponential notation for very small/large numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `%g` format specifier in the `printf`. Here is a simple program to demonstrate it:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    double pi=3.14;
    printf("%g\n",pi);
    pi=3.141;
    printf("%g\n",pi);
    pi=3.1415;
    printf("%g\n",pi);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3.14
3.141
3.1415
```